# Flex Import Class from a Module within a sub directory

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, import, module, subdirectory

I put some modules in a module folder. How do I import classes with the import statement when I'm in a sub folder?

This won't work, not like classes which are in packages.
modules/SomeModule.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mx:Module>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        import Fruit.Apple;
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Module>
```

Directory:

```
.
|-- Fruit
    |-- Apple.as
|-- Modules
    |-- SomeModule.mxml
`-- application.mxml
```

Comment: what kind of error are you getting?  that should work

Answer (score 0):

This should work as long as the src folder is set to the above directory and the Apple class has the correct package declaration (`package Fruit { ... }`)

Comment: The SomeModule.mxml class isn't in the "above folder", it's in the sub folder modules.

Comment: Do you have an error message? Because your code looks correct, so I don't really know where this thing breaks.